# System.IO.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine - Exchange Online

Tags: exchange-server, imap

We have an Windows application which connect to a mailbox in Exchange Online and fetches some attachments from an email.
In order to connect we are using Oauth2.0 and IMAP. It looks like the connection is aborted by Exchange for some reason. Any advise?

2023-10-06 15:39:07,884 [6] INFO  Lodgical.ScanMan.EmailMonitorService.Imap.MailKitImapClient - Connecting to outlook.office365.com:993 as *****@*****.com
2023-10-06 15:41:23,288 [6] ERROR Lodgical.ScanMan.EmailMonitorService.MailReader - Failed to connect to server
System.IO.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at MailKit.Net.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

Connection to a exchange online application.
The connection was aborted.

Comment: Like every networking tool, some amount of connections being closed is normal.  Put it in a loop and reconnect, with an exponential backoff.  
If this is happening frequently or predictably, after the same command or something, you're doing something the server doesn't like (logging in too frequently, sending a bad command, not watching your IDLE connections)